# Django nested QuerySets

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a Django data model like this (data fields omitted):

```
class Atom(Model):
    pass

class State(Model):
    atom = ForeignKey(Atom)

class Transition(Model):
    atom = ForeignKey(Atom)
    upstate = ForeignKey(State,related_name='uptrans')
    lostate = ForeignKey(State,related_name='lotrans')
```

When I query, the fields to be restricted can be in either model, so it is easiest to query on `Transition.objects.filter(...)` since all fields in the other models can be reached through the foreign keys. Let's call the resulting QuerySet `t`.

Now what I want in addition is a QuerySet `a` of the Atom model that corresponds to `t`, which can be done like `a = t.values('atom').distinct()`. So far so good.

However, I also want each of the entries in `a` to have *one* attribute/field that holds the QuerySet for the States of this Atom, still reflecting the criteria on the original selection `t`, through either one of the `upstate` or `lostate` ForeignKeys.

I have created my QuerySet on States up to now by looping over `t`, adding the `values('upstate_id')` and `values('lostate_id')` to a Python `set()` for throwing out duplicates, and then querying States with this list. But then I cannot achieve the nested structure of States within Atoms.

Any suggestions on how to do this are welcome, if possible with unevaluated `QuerySet`s, since I pass them not into a template but a generator (`yield` statements), which is a nice way of streaming large amounts of data.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following function does what I describe above, but I am not sure if the loop with further filtering of the original QuerySet by atom is the right approach.

```
def getAtomsWithStates(t):
    atom_ids = set( t.values_list('atom_id',flat=True) )
    atoms = Atoms.objects.filter(pk__in=atom_ids)
    for atom in atoms:
        upstate_ids = t.filter(atom=atom).values_list('upstate_id',flat=True)
        lostate_ids = t.filter(atom=atom).values_list('lostate_id',flat=True)
        all_ids = set( upstate_ids + lostate_ids )

        # attach the new QuerySet to the entry in the outer one:
        atom.States = State.objects.filter(pk__in=all_ids)

    return atoms
```

Now I can do the nested loop that I need like this:

```
someAtoms = getAtomsWithStates( Transition.objects.filter(...) )
for atom in someAtoms:
    for state in atom.States:
        print state.field
```

But, once again, there might be a smarter solution for this and I'd surely be interested.

Answer (score 1):

It is very nice that you have the understanding of `set`s.  However, using SQL's `In` will not duplicate your data.  Let's consider that for a moment.  If I say, "Give me an atom that is in this list: (1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4)," the database will return atoms 1, 2, 3, and 4.  For simplification, I would not ask Python to perform the `set` arithmetic since the database should be able to handle it just fine.  There are times to use `set`, but your scenario doesn't seem like one of them.

An alternative for you:

```
states = State.objects.filter(
    Q(pk__in=t.values_list('upstate', flat=True)) |
    Q(pk__in=t.values_list('lostate', flat=True)
)
```

Even so, it seems like your model could use some changes, but I don't fully understand what you're trying to accomplish.  Notice how that in my alternative, I don't do anything with atoms.  I use the `Q` object to be able to perform an OR operation, but you might be able to add a flag to the State model to indicate if it is high or low.  Or you could use an M2M relation with a through table.  And why would your transition and your state both be associated with an atom?  You could just eliminate `atom` from `Transition` and get the `atom` from `State` like so:

```
atoms = Atom.objects.filter(
    pk__in=State.objects.filter(
        Q(pk__in=t.values_list('upstate', flat=True)) |
        Q(pk__in=t.values_list('lostate', flat=True)
    ).values_list('atom', flat=True)
)
```